# Error adding android platform for phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to add the android platform using the following command

`cordova platform add android`

I am presented with the following output:

```
Creating android project...

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'which'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user1/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:27:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
Error: /Users/user1/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I have set the `PATH` in my bash_rc file as such:

`export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/user1/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/user1/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools`

I was able to add iOS as a platform. I have updated to the latest Android SDK as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/user1/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/user1/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
```

Should be:

```
export PATH=/Users/user1/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/user1/android-sdk-macosx/tools:$PATH
```

You have `platform-tools` twice, missing `tools` and `${PATH}` should be `$PATH`

Comment: Hmm, I got the same error. I also tried reinstalling Cordova with `sudo npm -g uninstall cordova` followed by `sudo npm -g install cordova`. That didn't seem to change either though.